# Mysterious duplicate entries in SQLite table when using INSERT

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, insert

Before I used PDO and it worked fine but I had problems with inserting pictures. Now I switched to SQLite3 and the pictures are now stored correctly. But I'm  experiencing a strange problem with SQLite3. Every `INSERT INTO` command is done twice. And this only concerns `INSERT`, because I had no problems with `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

This is my test script

```
<?php
    require_once('class.DatabaseQuery.php');
    $db = new DatabaseQuery();

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Bezeichnungen(Bezeichnung_de,Bezeichnung_en,Bezeichnung_it) values("test","test","test");';
    $result = $db->ExecuteQuery($sql);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This is my database class:

```
<?php
    class DatabaseQuery {
        private $_handle;

        public function ExecuteQuery($sql, $params = array())
        {

            echo $sql;
            echo "<strong>execute Query params</strong><pre>";
            print_r ($params);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo count($params);


            // make new connection if not available
            if($this->_handle == null)
                $this->Connect();
            // make prepared statement
            $query = $this->_handle->prepare($sql);
            // add values to prepared statement depending on type
            foreach($params as $key => $value)
            {
                if(is_int($value)){
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
                }else if(is_null($value)){
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, SQLITE3_NULL);
                }else if(strpos($value, "home/www/") !== false){
                    $value=file_get_contents($value);
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, SQLITE3_BLOB);
                    $value="X'" . strtoupper(bin2hex($value));
                }else{
                    $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                }
            }
            $result = $query->execute();

            // get all results
            while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
                $res[] = $row;
            }

            //var_dump($x);

            return $res;
        }

        public function Connect()
        {
            $this->_handle = new SQLite3("database.db");
        }

        public function Disconnect()
        {
            // close database connection
            $this->_handle->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

And this is the create statement of my table

```
CREATE TABLE Bezeichnungen
(
_id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Bezeichnung_de   TEXT,
Bezeichnung_en   TEXT,
Bezeichnung_it   TEXT
)
```

Either I'm using SQLite3 the wrong way or the used library has a bug.

I'm using PHP 5.3.9, SQLite3 module version 0.7-dev and SQLite Library 3.7.7.1.

Perhaps someone can test my code on his plattform and tells me if he has the same problem.